# (index):49 Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

```
ViewBag.Image = '<image>https://c152688.ssl.cf3.rackcdn.com/tcthh/v10/bg/light/random/singaporecity_light_1280.jpg'
```

I am trying to pass an image URL from controller to view using viewbag. In the view I am trying to assign the value to a div.

```
<script>
$('#logindiv').css("background-image", "url('" + @ViewBag.Image + "')");
</script>
```

But the above line gives me

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list error.

Comment: When asking other people to help you, please take the time to spell and punctuate correctly, and do at least minimal markup so we can tell what's meant to be code and what isn't. When saying you got an error, say *what from* (the ASP.Net compiler? the web browser? something else?) and quote the error verbatim using quote markup. I've fixed the above as best I can.

Comment: About line `ViewBag.Image = '....' ` -> because of the single quotes it **can't be C# code**. But given the **`ViewBag`** name it looks like you are trying to set a .NET variable from Javascript, which is impossible because one runs in the browser (Javascript) and the other runs on the server (C#/.NET).

Comment: Have a look at your *rendered* HTML (view-source in the browser) and it should be clear what the issue is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue is that the image URL should not have the `<image>` tag in it. That needs to be removed.

The second issue is that you're appending the content from the ViewBag on the server side. As such you don't need to concatenate it to the client side JS. You just need to output it in the correct position within the JS.

```csharp
ViewBag.Image = 'https://c152688.ssl.cf3.rackcdn.com/tcthh/v10/bg/light/random/singaporecity_light_1280.jpg'
```

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $('#logindiv').css("background-image", 'url("@ViewBag.Image")');
});
```

Note that the JS has to run after the DOM has loaded, which is why I added the document.ready handler, and also the JS needs to be executed within the View so that the `@` Razor/Blazor syntax will be interpreted. If your JS is contained within an external `.js` file, your current approach will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
$('#logindiv').css("background-image", 'url(" + @ViewBag.Image + ")');
```

Comment: Please send me the page link.